# Angular: declare a const with several time the same field

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to declare a const using several times the same fields.

```js
const myexample = {
    value: 8,
    name: name1,
    name: name2,
    name: name3    
};
```

I dont't know how many names I'll get and I don't want to declare it as an array.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you say why the names should not be an array except that you don't 'want' it.

Comment: I think the short answer here is "you can't". Here's a thought experiment for you: if I tried to access something called `name`, how would it know which one to give me?

Comment: thanks , best answer !

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
let [value, name1, name2, name3] = [8, 'name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this this way. Objects can not have duplicate keys.
Maybe try this way:

```
const myExample = { value: 1, names: [name1, name2, name3] };
```